# Boost Python pointer to empty memory

Tags: python, c++, boost, steam

I'm trying to expose this function using Boost Python:

```
int SteamUser_InitiateGameConnection(void *AuthBlob, int MaxAuthBlob,
                                CSteamID steamIDGameServer, uint32 IPServer,
                                              uint16 PortServer, bool Secure) {

return SteamUser()->InitiateGameConnection(AuthBlob, MaxAuthBlob,
                             steamIDGameServer, IPServer, PortServer, Secure); };
```

I don't have any clue how I pass as an argument, a pointer to empty memory that will be filled.
I've searched but didn't find any answer for my problem.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You could allocate 2048 bytes (malloc or new, zero with memset) and pass it to the function as *AuthBlob* and `MaxAuthBlob=2048`.

Comment: Can you post a sample?
I'm not well versed with C/C++

And thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm not so familiar with boost::python. Furthermore, the one asking here a question is usually expected to show at least some code (i.e. a show of effort).